# Example of a Binomial Test

Tags: r, testing, statistics

Example for a binomial Test:
We have 44 questions and A answers them correctly 35 times. The probability of getting a answer correctly without knowing is 89%. We want to compute a two sided p value at a 90% confidence. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer it is:

```
binom.test(35, 44, p = 0.89, alternative = c("two.sided"), conf.level = 0.90)
```